# Axios - unable to set global Authorization header

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a VueJS vue-cli app with Axios and I would like to set global Authorization header with a token I receive after I sign in so that I can re-use it in all subsequent requests. This is my code.

## main.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store'

console.log(store.state)
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://54.38.36.242'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.getters.token
```

When I set the header like this the browser console says:
`Authorization: [object Object]`. Why?

After I login `console.log(store.state)` shows me that the token has been received and set in the store.

## store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    apiToken: null,
    user: null,
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    authenticateUser(state, payload) {
      state.apiToken = payload.token
      state.user = payload.user
      state.signedIn = true
    },
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, payload){
      axios.post('/api/users/login', payload)
        .then(response => {
          commit('authenticateUser', {
            token: response.data.api_token,
            user: response.data.user
          })
          router.replace('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch(error => {
          commit('signInError')
        })
    },
    ...
  },
  getters: {
    token: state => {
      return state.apiToken;
    }
  }
})
```

I have tried accessing the token by `store.state.apiToken` but it didn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want a request interceptor so you can fetch the API token from the store each time. Otherwise, you're only ever setting it to the initial value, which is `null`

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `response.data.api_token` is not a pure string but an object. If you change your header-setting line to:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = JSON.stringify(store.getters.token)
```

the problem should be easier to diagnose.

Also, unless you do something bespoke, you also need to set an authorization type in the header value, so that the value becomes `Bearer <token>` or `Basic <token>`

Comment: In mutation `authenticateUser` I did `console.log(payload.token)` and it's a pure string and it's a perfectly valid token. If I set `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + store.state.apiToken` the header looks like this `Authorization:Bearer null`. Am I missing something? Why is the token null since it's a string in `state.apiToken`